# C function macro to take NSString placeholders

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

In my IOS-Project, I have a custom Logger-class (singleton) containing the function

```
- (void)log:(NSString *)domain logLevel:(int)level logMessage:(NSString *)message
```

which is globally available through the following preprocessor macro:

```
#define MyLog(domain, level, message) [[MyLogger sharedInstance] log:domain logLevel:level logMessage:message]
```

Now when I make the call:

```
MyLog(@"common", LL_ERROR, @"There was an error!");
```

Everything works fine. But in practice, the logMessage will sometimes contain string placeholders. So the big question is:
How can I make my macro accept calls like

```
MyLog(@"common", LL_ERROR, @"There was an error: %@", [error debugDescription]);
```

With the current solution, Xcode complains: "Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to change your `log` method to take a "variable argument list",
for example like this:

```
- (void)log:(NSString *)domain logLevel:(int)level logMessage:(NSString *)message, ...
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, message);
    NSString *fullMessage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:message arguments:argList];
    va_end(argList);

    NSLog(@"domain:%@, level:%d: %@", domain, level, fullMessage);
}
```

Then you have to change your `MyLog` macro to work with a variable number of arguments.
This is a GNU feature (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html), that works
with Clang as well:

```
#define MyLog(domain, level, message, ...) \
   [[MyLogger sharedInstance] log:domain logLevel:level logMessage:message, ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

Now

```
MyLog(@"common", LL_ERROR, @"There was an error!");
MyLog(@"common", LL_ERROR, @"There was an error: %@", [error debugDescription]);
```

should both work without problems.

Comment: Thank you.. What would be the solution for NSArray arguments??